# Problems with inline tags next to DIV tags when PUGs are compiled

Tags: gulp, pug-loader

PUG is being compiled into HTML using GULP.
If you are using a gulp-pug and use the Pretty option to true, the code is composing strangely.

I've solved the problem with the gulp-html-beauty, and the only thing that bothers me.

the current situation

```
<div class="box"><strong class="title">믹스인 만들기</strong>
    <ul>
```

what i want

```
<div class="box">
    <strong class="title">믹스인 만들기</strong>
    <ul>
```

help me... please